# Does not return value in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm seeking for your help to help me solve this matter. I've been stuck doing this almost 1 month. I've create a drop down list for list item value :*OPTO, Tool Room, IMP, PHL & Other Process* so it will return listing for each module. The result should be every module will show for every respective list item value. But when I try to debug, the value with create another list item value e.g; 2 times OPTO.

Here my coding for aspx.vb :

```
    If (DropDownList.SelectedValue = "OPTO") Then
        myConnection = New SqlConnection("server=mtmwhs;uid=sa;pwd=private;database=elearning")
'you need to provide password for sql server
        myConnection.Open()
        myCommand = New SqlCommand("update EmployeePrivacy set DateRead4=@time where emp_id = '" & userNameLabel.Text & "'", myConnection)
        reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader()
        If (reader.Read()) Then


            Session("emp_username") = reader("emp_username")
            If (DropDownList.SelectedValue = "") Then
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, Page.GetType(), "ErrorMsg", "alert('Please choose your option.');", True)
                DropDownList.Focus()
            Else
                Response.Redirect("optomodule.aspx")
            End If
            reader.Close()
            myConnection.Close()
        End If
    End If

    If (DropDownList.SelectedValue = "PHL") Then
        myConnection = New SqlConnection("server=mtmwhs;uid=sa;pwd=private;database=elearning")
'you need to provide password for sql server
        myConnection.Open()
        myCommand = New SqlCommand("update EmployeePrivacy set DateRead4=@time where emp_id = '" & userNameLabel.Text & "'", myConnection)
        reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader()
        If (reader.Read()) Then


            Session("emp_username") = reader("emp_username")
            If (DropDownList.SelectedValue = "") Then
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, Page.GetType(), "ErrorMsg", "alert('Please choose your option.');", True)
                DropDownList.Focus()
            Else
                Response.Redirect("phlmodule.aspx")
            End If
            reader.Close()
            myConnection.Close()
        End If
    End If

    If (DropDownList.SelectedValue = "IMP") Then
        myConnection = New SqlConnection("server=mtmwhs;uid=sa;pwd=private;database=elearning")
'you need to provide password for sql server
        myConnection.Open()
        myCommand = New SqlCommand("update EmployeePrivacy set DateRead4=@time where emp_id = '" & userNameLabel.Text & "'", myConnection)
        reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader()
        If (reader.Read()) Then


            Session("emp_username") = reader("emp_username")
            If (DropDownList.SelectedValue = "") Then
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, Page.GetType(), "ErrorMsg", "alert('Please choose your option.');", True)
                DropDownList.Focus()
            Else
                Response.Redirect("impmodule.aspx")
            End If
            reader.Close()
            myConnection.Close()
        End If
    End If

    If (DropDownList.SelectedValue = "Tool Room") Then
        myConnection = New SqlConnection("server=mtmwhs;uid=sa;pwd=private;database=elearning")
'you need to provide password for sql server
        myConnection.Open()
        myCommand = New SqlCommand("update EmployeePrivacy set DateRead4=@time where emp_id = '" & userNameLabel.Text & "'", myConnection)
        reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader()
        If (reader.Read()) Then


            Session("emp_username") = reader("emp_username")
            If (DropDownList.SelectedValue = "") Then
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, Page.GetType(), "ErrorMsg", "alert('Please choose your option.');", True)
                DropDownList.Focus()
            Else
                Response.Redirect("trmodule.aspx")
            End If
            reader.Close()
            myConnection.Close()
        End If
    End If

    If (DropDownList.SelectedValue = "Other Process") Then
        myConnection = New SqlConnection("server=mtmwhs;uid=sa;pwd=private;database=elearning")
'you need to provide password for sql server
        myConnection.Open()
        myCommand = New SqlCommand("update EmployeePrivacy set DateRead4=@time where emp_id = '" & userNameLabel.Text & "'", myConnection)
        reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader()
        If (reader.Read()) Then


            Session("emp_username") = reader("emp_username")
            If (DropDownList.SelectedValue = "") Then
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, Page.GetType(), "ErrorMsg", "alert('Please choose your option.');", True)
                DropDownList.Focus()
            Else
                Response.Redirect("otherprocessmodule.aspx")
            End If
            reader.Close()
            myConnection.Close()
        End If
    End If
```

Thank you.

Comment: You should cut down the code to only include the relevant area related to the question.

Comment: That's a lot of code to go thru..... Please share only code relevant to the problem you are facing.

Comment: Mandatory read [MCVE]

Comment: I hope the SQL credentials get reset, never show them on a public site.

Comment: Already cut down unnecessary code. Just leave relevant code.

Comment: I suggest you look at creating method, this logic can be simplified a lot with smaller function being called. This would greatly help at finding bugs.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to give "DropDownList" a better name. I chose "LocationOptions".

Then make sure the dropdown is not populated more than once, so only create its items when the page is first run, not in the event of a postback:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Loa
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        ' Create items in LocationOptions dropdown.
    End If

    ' other code...

End Sub
```

---

Then you need to tidy up the code shown in the question. Notice how the same thing is done over and over again but the only actual change is the redirect location. So, we can create a variable for the redirect location and use it in just one copy of that code.

I noticed that you have an UPDATE command instead of a SELECT command. That latter command will have to be written.

You will have to change the password for the sa account on the SQL Server because now the whole world knows what it is.

You need to create a different user in SQL Server for this project and give it the very least permissions possible for it to work. I recommend that you document which tables and stored procedures are used for which purposes.

Some of the intent of the code eluded me, but I think this is close to it:

```
If LocationOptions.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, Page.GetType(), "ErrorMsg", "alert('Please choose your option.');", True)
    LocationOptions.Focus()
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim selectedLocation = LocationOptions.SelectedValue
Dim userName = userNameLabel.Text

Dim redirectUrl As String = Nothing

Select Case selectedLocation
    Case "OPTO"
        redirectUrl = "optomodule.aspx"
    Case "PHL"
        redirectUrl = "phlmodule.aspx"
    Case "IMP"
        redirectUrl = "impmodule.aspx"
    Case "Tool Room"
        redirectUrl = "trmodule.aspx"
    Case "Other Process"
        redirectUrl = "otherprocessmodule.aspx"
End Select

'TODO: create variables for the SELECT criteria
Dim someValue = "appropriate value"

'TODO: Stop using the sa login.
'TODO: Change the sa password because everyone knows it now.
'TODO: Use the correct credentials.
Using sqlConn = New SqlConnection("server=mtmwhs;uid=elearningUser;pwd=neverExposeYourPassword;database=elearning")
    'TODO: Write the correct SQL query.
    Using sqlCmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT emp_username FROM [tableName] WHERE [someColumn] = @someValue", sqlConn)
        ' this is an example of adding an SQL parameter:
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {
                              .ParameterName = "@someValue",
                              .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar,
                              .Size = 30,
                              .Value = someValue})

        sqlConn.Open()

        Dim reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader()

        If reader.Read() Then
            Session("emp_username") = reader("emp_username")
            Response.Redirect(redirectUrl)
        End If

    End Using

End Using
```

The [`Using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) statement makes sure that things are kept tidy, such as avoiding memory leaks and running out of SQL connections.

Comment: Dear Andrew Morton, Thank you for your answer. I've try using your command and it says "LocationOptions is not declared". Can you suggest me how to fix it?

Comment: @airina Please refer to the first sentence of my answer: that is what I named the dropdown.